# Inheriting Airflow OracleHook in order to set cx_Oracle outputtypehandler due to SELECT ValueError

Tags: python, oracle, airflow, cx-oracle

I am querying a full table that is very old. It contains some corrupted data that I do not have the privileges to change or create a view from. Whenever I SELECT the data using the [Airflow](https://github.com/apache/airflow) OracleHook get_records I get the error message "ValueError: year -4712 is out of range". I would like to handle this by returning None for this particular record as shown in this cx_Oracle solution: [Problem empty date cause ValueError: year -9999 is out of range](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/347#issuecomment-525253126). This requires setting the [cx_Oracle outputtypehandler](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html?highlight=outputtypehandler#querying-corrupt-data) attribute. When I run the following code, neither the OutputHandler or DateTimeConverter functions are called and the code fails with the same ValueError as when I use the base OracleHook class. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from airflow.hooks.oracle_hook import OracleHook
import cx_Oracle

from datetime import datetime
import os
os.environ['NLS_DATE_FORMAT'] = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

class OracleHookTypeHandler(OracleHook):
    def __init__(self, oracle_conn_id):
        OracleHook.__init__(self, oracle_conn_id)
        self.cursor = OracleHook.get_cursor
        self.cursor.outputtypehandler = self.OutputHandler

    # Dealing with invalid years in the database
    def DateTimeConverter(self, value):
        print('DateTimeConverter was called')
        if value.startswith('4712'):
            return None
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    def OutputHandler(self, cursor, name, defaulttype, length, precision, scale):
        print('OutputHandler was called')
        if defaulttype == cx_Oracle.DATETIME:
            return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize,
                              outconverter=self.DateTimeConverter)

def extract(extract_connection)
    # Return the extracted records
    extract_records_query = 'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table'
    o_extract_hook = OracleHookTypeHandler(oracle_conn_id=extract_connection)
    print('Extract started')
    extract_records = o_extract_hook.get_records(sql=extract_records_query)
    return extract_records
```

**Update:**
I solved this using the answer from @joebeeson below. Working code:

```
from airflow.hooks.oracle_hook import OracleHook
import cx_Oracle
import sys

from datetime import datetime
from contextlib import closing
import os
os.environ['NLS_DATE_FORMAT'] = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

class OracleHookTypeHandler(OracleHook):
    def __init__(self, oracle_conn_id):
        OracleHook.__init__(self, oracle_conn_id)

    # Override get_records from inherited class dbapihook
    def get_records(self, sql, parameters=None):
        """
        Executes the sql and returns a set of records.

        :param sql: the sql statement to be executed (str) or a list of
            sql statements to execute
        :type sql: str or list
        :param parameters: The parameters to render the SQL query with.
        :type parameters: mapping or iterable
        """
        if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
            sql = sql.encode('utf-8')

        with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
            with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
    
                cur.outputtypehandler = self.OutputHandler

                if parameters is not None:
                    cur.execute(sql, parameters)
                else:
                    cur.execute(sql)
                return cur.fetchall()

    # Dealing with invalid years in the database
    def DateTimeConverter(self, value):
        print('DateTimeConverter was called')
        if value.startswith('4712'):
            return None
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    def OutputHandler(self, cursor, name, defaulttype, length, precision, scale):
        print('OutputHandler was called')
        if defaulttype == cx_Oracle.DATETIME:
            return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize,
                              outconverter=self.DateTimeConverter)

def extract(extract_connection)
    # Return the extracted records
    extract_records_query = 'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table'
    o_extract_hook = OracleHookTypeHandler(oracle_conn_id=extract_connection)
    print('Extract started')
    extract_records = o_extract_hook.get_records(sql=extract_records_query)
    return extract_records
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to override the `get_records` method from the `airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook.DbapiHook` class; it doesn't call out to `OracleHook.get_cursor` so your assignments won't work:

```py
def get_records(self, sql, parameters=None):
    """
    Executes the sql and returns a set of records.

    :param sql: the sql statement to be executed (str) or a list of
        sql statements to execute
    :type sql: str or list
    :param parameters: The parameters to render the SQL query with.
    :type parameters: mapping or iterable
    """
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        sql = sql.encode('utf-8')

    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
        with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
 
            # You have access to the `Cursor` (named "cur") object.

            if parameters is not None:
                cur.execute(sql, parameters)
            else:
                cur.execute(sql)
            return cur.fetchall()
```

Although it might be cleaner to lift the portions of code you need into the process file that needs these modifications.